# Can I convince an employer to hire me by demanding lower salary in resume?

Tags: resume, hiring, entry-level, junior

I want to a get visa sponsored job and that's the reason why the amount of salary doesn't matter to me for now. So can I use it to convince the employer to hire me? And I want to write it in my resume because I don't get any respond to my applicants.

I have only six month related job experience and I've found many visa sponsored job advertisement that want's a junior/entry-level php  developer.

Comment: Normally visa schemes have minim salary requirements  and  I am afraid your country of origin will limit you - which countries have you applied for

Comment: Not quite the question asked, but sounding like you mainly want the job to get a visa during the interview process is very bad. You should be interested in the work and the company (not pretend to be interested, actually be interested). You probably shouldn't even bring up visa sponsorship as a reason for wanting the job at all (but you should convince them that you're motivated to work, and settle down, where they are, especially if you're not already there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Be careful selling yourself cheap. If you offer yourself too cheap people might think you are not good or have some bad issues.**

You should mention that the sponsored visa is important for you.

If an employer wants you but only wants to hire you for a lower salary it is likely that the employer will tell you this. And then I think you can show that you are willing to work for less because the visa is important for you.

Answer (score 7):

Think of it like buying a used car.  You go to the lot looking for a reliable car at a fair price.  The dealer shows you a car that meets your requirements and adds, "and we're selling it for 50% below the blue book value."  You'd probably be suspicious.  Is it really what he says it is?  Maybe the previous owner didn't get regular oil changes and the engine is corroded. Maybe the brakes are no good. Maybe the battery is about to give out.

Hiring managers want smart, reliable employees that will do the job they're assigned and add value to the company more than they want to save money on salary.  This is why I believe it's always better to sell yourself in terms of what you will bring to the company and leave salary negotiation for the very end, after they've already decided they want to hire you.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how hiring works from an employers point of view.  They are looking for a certain combination of skills and experience to do a particular job.

I can understand where you're coming from as this has been an issue in IT since the "bad old days".  When I first started in IT back in the early 90's with my freshly minted degree in programming (in COBOL, ugh) companies were extremely hesitant to developers with no practical, real world experience in development.  So I took a job in operations working in a data center.  This got some experience in the 'other' things needed and allowed me to move into development several years later.  Now I'm on an R&D team doing some really fun stuff with some of the newer technologies.